# How to add more than one values to a key in qjsonobject

Tags: c++, json, qt, json-rpc

I want to generate a qjsonstring in this format:

```
{"id": 1, "params":[1,2,3]}
```

But I don't know how to add several values [1,2,3] to key "params"

This is my code:

```
 QJsonObject *jsonObj = new QJsonObject();
 jsonObj->insert("id",1);
 jsonObj->insert("params",[1,2,3]);
 QJsonDocument *jsonDoc = new QJsonDocument(*jsonObj);
 QString jsonString = jsonDoc->toJson(QJsonDocument::Indented);
```

Can anyone help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can just replace `[1, 2, 3]` with `{ 1, 2, 3 }`:

```
jsonObj->insert("params", { 1, 2, 3 });
```

If it doesn't, there's another compact way:

```
jsonObj->insert("params", QJsonArray() << 1 << 2 << 3);
```

BTW: I hope you're correctly deleting `new`-ed `jsonObj` and `jsonDoc`.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot @tonytony

Comment: {"id": 1, "params":{ "parameter1" : 1, "parameter2": 2, "parameter3" :3}}  do you know how to generate this jsonobject?  thanks @tonytony

Comment: @newww0 Create QJsonObject with fields "parameter1", "parameter2", "parameter3" just like you created your top-level object, then add it to your top-level object using `insert` method or `operator[]`.